# Is it possible to remove the type "string" from a union of strings in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, union-types

I have a very particular case where typescript types are being generated from an API definition and for some fields, it generates a type like this:

```
type Foo = 'foo' | 'bar' | string
```

And I would like to find a way to remove the `string` from the type and get only `'foo' | 'bar'`.

e.g.

```
type NarrowFoo = RemoveStringButKeepConstants<Foo>
//    ^? 'foo' | 'bar'
```

Is there a way to implement the type `RemoveStringButKeepConstants`?

I thought of trying somethings like:

```
type Attempt1 = Exclude<Foo, string> // don't work
//    ^? never
type Attempt2 = `${Foo}` // don't work, not 'foo' | 'bar'
//    ^? string
```

Also thought of using [const type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters), but I couldn't figure out how to use it.

Comment: AFAIK, the only way to do this would be through a TypeScript AST parser — by parsing the generated, raw source text ([example](https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKAiAZg1UA+aBGAhgE7Z4DOwxAlgHYDmA3AFBA)). At the time of compilation, `Foo` is just `string` because the literals are absorbed in the union, so there's no opportunity to extract them.

Comment: I don't think this is possible the way you're trying. Sounds like an XY problem to me. How did you end up with `Foo`? It might be possible to exclude `string` at an earlier stage. Maybe I don't understand what do you mean by "generated from an API definition".

Comment: Whatever is generating those definitions doesn't understand typescript properly. The `type Foo = 'foo' | 'bar' | string` is exactly equivalent to `type Foo = string`

Comment: @LazarLjubenović "generated from an API definition" means that another team have an API that generates some file for it's definitions (e.g. json file that details every endpoint). There's another tool that take the file for the API definitions and generate the typescript types.

Comment: @Vencovsky I don't know how your organizational structure works, but you need to send them a bug report because they're not simply generating unhelpful types, they're generating nonsensical types. Just reading those types is likely to confuse people

Comment: At least tell them to generate `string` with `string & {}` instead... Then you'll at least have autocomplete!

Answer (score 1):

1. If it's a literal

```
type Foo = 'foo' | 'bar' | string;
```

then it'll be just merged into

```
type Foo = /* just */ string;
```

then there is nothing you can do with that type-wise. You'll have to use codegen (maybe just some manual regex replacers) to split them as descriped further.

2. If you want your type to be literal/whole union at once, they have to be unmergeable types, then you can split off the `string`, roughly like this:

```
type A1 = string & { _?: 1 } | 'A' & { _?: 2 }
type A2 = string | 'A' & { _?: 2 }
type A3 = string & { _?: 1 } | 'A'

type ExcludeString<T> =
    | T extends string ? (
        string extends T ? never
        : T /* maybe literal, not the whole `string` */
    )
    : T /* not a string */
type AAA1 = ExcludeString<A1>
//   ^?
// type AAA1 = "A" & { _?: 2 | undefined; }
type AAA2 = ExcludeString<A2>
//   ^?
// type AAA2 = "A" & { _?: 2 | undefined; }
type AAA3 = ExcludeString<A3>
//   ^?
// type AAA3 = "A"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `isLiteral<..>` type from [type-fest](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/is-literal.d.ts). (Or just copy that specific set of type definitions into your codebase.)

Then I think you should be able to accomplish what you want with a helper type like this:

```js
type Foo = 'foo' | 'bar' | string

type RemoveStringButKeepConstants<T> = IsLiteral<T> extends true ? T : never

type NarrowFoo = RemoveStringButKeepConstants<Foo>
```

Comment: I'm actually getting `type NarrowFoo = never`

Comment: Could you provide a working example? Thanks!